# Getting [Object,Object] in angular JS when reading List of Objects

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to read the data from list of Objects where in backend call I am getting proper JSON format but when calling from angular js using response.data getting [Object,Object] as a list. I am getting the data as response.data[0].id but I need to use the data to a $scope variable with data to use further.

```
[{id : '1',name:'Test'},{id:'2',name'Test1'}]
```

I need to get the same JSON object in angular as same as backend. I am new to AngularJS. Please let me know how I can proceed with this without pushing to any other variable.

Comment: Why do you get when doing a `console.log(JSON.stringify(reponse.data));` ?

Comment: show me your response .. u can also put object data in $scope variable

Comment: show more of your code please.

Comment: JSON.stringify(reponse.data) gives me the JSON data , I am trying to use alasql to convert json to xls but the not able to render JSON data. Thanks Zakaria it works!!!